# Is it syntactically and semantically correct to say "Too many open windows."

Tags: meaning-in-context, semantic-roles

As a response to a complaint about the coldness of a room if we reply with saying **"Too many open windows."**  will it be syntactically and semantically correct? 
Or do we need to say **"Too many opened windows."** to be syntactically correct?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, neither response is grammatical because neither contains a verb. An English sentence must contain a verb. However, sentence fragments lacking a verb are common in informal speech and sloppy writing so let's deal with the substance of your question.

**Open** is both a verb describing an action and an adjective describing a state. The past and present participles of verbs may be used as adjectives.

Thus both **The reason that the room is too cold is that there are too many open windows** and **The reason that the room is too cold is that there are too many opened windows** are both grammatical sentences. But the second would be far less common, perhaps even not idiomatic. When a native speaker chooses a word to be used adjectivaly, the pure adjective is far more likely to be chosen than a participle when both forms stem from the same root.

Comment: What is this "technically"? Who decreed that speakers of English must always do so in grammatically "correct" sentences. News for you: they don't. There is nothing whatever wrong with the OP's proposed answer to the question.

Comment: You are of course correct that many do not speak or write grammatically. But the actual question was asked what was grammatically correct so I first answered that question. I then went on to say the more important question of whether to use the adjective or participle. And  I continue to say that although **opened window** is grammatical, what is more idiomatic in the context given is **open window**.

Comment: Where I think we disagree is in contrasting the language as it is used with what is 'correct grammatically'. If what is 'correct grammatically' does not correspond with the language as it is used , then so much the worse for ideas of grammatical correctness.  We can all construct rules as to how our language should be spoken "grammatically" but the language is defined not by such rules but by how it is in fact spoken. The grammarians just have to keep updating their "rules"; you can't expect native speakers to adapt what they say to rules propounded by grammarians.